# Cómo pongo como en evento al método paint?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FrmCirColor extends JFrame
{

    private int X;
    private int Y;
    private JLabel LBPosX;
    private JLabel LBPosY;
    private JLabel LBBarra;

    private JTextField TFPosX;
    private JTextField TFPosY;
    //private JTextField TFBarra;
    private JButton BTNDibujar;
    public FrmCirColor()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        setTitle("Dibujo de un circulo");
        setSize(500,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        LBPosX = new JLabel("Posicion en X");
        LBPosY = new JLabel("Posicion en Y");
        LBBarra = new JLabel("Barra de Colores");

        TFPosX = new JTextField(8);
        TFPosY = new JTextField(8);
        //TFBarra = new JTextField(10);

        add(LBPosX);
        add(TFPosX);

        add(LBPosY);
        add(TFPosY);

        add(LBBarra);
        //add(TFBarra);

        LBPosX.setBounds(30, 20, 100, 22);
        TFPosX.setBounds(135, 20, 100, 22);

        LBPosY.setBounds(30, 47, 100, 22);
        TFPosY.setBounds(135, 47, 100, 22);

        LBBarra.setBounds(30, 74, 100, 22);

        BTNDibujar = new JButton("Dibujar");
        BTNDibujar.setBounds(30, 101, 100, 22);
        add(BTNDibujar);

        BTNDibujar.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                paint(Graphics G);
            }
        });


        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);

        }


        public void paint(Graphics G, int X, int Y)
        {
            super.paint(G);

            X = Integer.parseInt(TFPosX.getText());
            Y = Integer.parseInt(TFPosY.getText());

            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;

            G.fillOval(100, 100, X, Y);
        }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        FrmCirColor FMCC = new FrmCirColor();
    }

}
```

Comment: Puedes describir de mejor manera tu pregunta, es algo confusa.

Comment: Solo quiero colocar como evento al metodo paint en un botón, para que al momento de "clickar" dicho botón, se dibuje un circulo